# Does limit of "approximate zero set" converge to the zero set?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. 
Define the zero set by $\mathcal{Z}\triangleq\{x\in\mathbb{R}^m|f(x)=\mathbf{0}\}$ and an $\epsilon$-approximation of this set by $\mathcal{Z}_\epsilon\triangleq\{x\in\mathbb{R}^m|~||f(x)||\leq\epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Clearly $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq \mathcal{Z}_\epsilon$. Can one assume any condition on the function $f$ so that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}~\max_{x\in\mathcal{Z}_\epsilon}~\text{dist}(x,\mathcal{Z})=0,
$$
holds?

I know in general this doesn't hold by this example (function of a scalar variable): 
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{align}
0,\quad{x\leq 0};
\\
1/x,\quad x>0.
\end{align}
\right.
$$

I really appreciate any help or hint.
Thank you.

Comment: There are lots of questions of this form on Math SE. i..e can you put a condition on $f$ such that.... well of course you can... you just want the set of functions for which it holds. Do you have a more specific question in mind that you have accidentally oversimplified into this one?

Comment: @T_M Yes. The main problem was actually that $f$ is the gradient of a nonconvex $g$ function which is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and possibly non-monotone. The zero set is actually the set of critical points of $g$.

Comment: So you don't really know anything about this function other than its a gradient. I'm not sure what you are asking then. I mean the "condition" you can put on $f$ is just the result you need then....

Comment: @T_M Exactly. My question is that "what is the sufficient condition for $f$ or $g$ to have this limit property?"

Comment: I'm not sure I am being clear: I am criticizing this approach to asking a question by saying that unless you have more information, the only reasonable sufficient condition is that $g$ is a function for which $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \max_{x \in \mathcal{Z}_{\epsilon}}\mathrm{dist}(x,\mathcal{Z}) = 0$. Anything else is like a weird reverse engineering. If this is the result you need and you are willing to put a condition on $g$, then you should put exactly this condition on $g$ rather than disguising it as something else

Comment: @T_M I agree with your argument. I just don't know if this condition is realistic. I am searching for a sufficient condition just to make sure that it can hold with  standard assumptions. My intention is not disguising it. As you mentioned below, maybe continuity and boundedness would be enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continous and stays away from $0$ outside some fixed compact set then your claim holds.

Comment: +1 except "stays away from $0$" should be more precise, like $||f(x)||\geq c>0$ whenever $||x||$ is sufficiently large. Else $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=xe^{-|x|}$ is a counter-example as it  "stays away from zero" whenever $|x|>1$.

Comment: @Régis Thanks for the response. Sure, but that is a conjecture. The problem is that how to prove it concretely? What condition on $f$ can satisfy this property? Actually $f$ here is the gradient of a nonconvex $g$ function which is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and possibly non-monotone, i.e. $f=\nabla g$. It would be great if I can get conditions on $g$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying its conjecture. This is essentially exactly what can go wrong. If you are continuous on a compact set, then you have the result. But outside of a compact set, as you go to infinity, the function could be positive but decay to zero so that the set of points where it is less than $\epsilon$ is always large and far away from the compact set.

Comment: @T_M Maybe yes. If I restrict the domain to a bounded set, it should hold true. I think continuity plus boundedness of domain would be enough.

Comment: Your domain has to be compact, bounded is not enough. Otherwise your function could tend to zero on the boundary of the domain.